# How to stream mongo query response as csv?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have collection which contains more than 5 million records. I need to query and pass on the data to client as a csv file. Initially when the records used to be low, we have just looped and write it in to a file and sent to the client. But now as the record keeps growing, it consumes memory and we are facing issue. So in order to use stream I tried below,

```
   const cursor = Model.find(query)
        const transformer = (doc) => {
                return {
                    "Creator": doc.Entity_Creator,
                    "Action Date" : doc.E_Approve_Time,
                    "Remarks": doc.Entity_Comment
                }
            }
       
        let pat = path.join(__dirname, '../')
        var csvFilePath = '././downloads/' + ' Approved.csv'
        const filename = pat + csvFilePath
        res.setHeader('Content-disposition',`attachment;filename=${filename}`);
        res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/csv'})
        res.flushHeaders();

        var csvStream = fastCsv.format({headers: true}).transform(transformer)
        cursor.stream().pipe(csvStream).pipe(res)
```

But after downloading, I'm getting files with Object Object in a single columns. How to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: fastCsv is fast-csv module? Did you try fast-csv.writeStream in that case?

Comment: Are you able to get the header names in the file?

Comment: @sasi yes, but I got writestream is not a function err. please suggest

Comment: @Lokesh I have attached the image. please check and suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
        const transformer = (doc) => {
          return {
            Creator: doc.Entity_Creator,
            "Action Date": doc.E_Approve_Time,
            Remarks: doc.Entity_Comment,
          };
        };
        
        let pat = path.join(__dirname, "../");
        var csvFilePath = "././downloads/" + " Approved.csv";
        const filename = pat + csvFilePath;
        res.setHeader("Content-disposition", `attachment;filename=${filename}`);
        res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/csv" });
        res.flushHeaders();
        
        var csvStream = fastCsv.format({ headers: true }).transform(transformer);
        
        csvStream.pipe(process.stdout).on("end", () => process.exit());
        
        Model.find(query).exec(function (err, cursor) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log('error returned');
                    return false;
                }
               if (!data) {
                    console.log('Authentication Failed');
                    return false;
                }
        cursor.forEach((e) => {
          csvStream.write({
            Creator: e.Entity_Creator,
            "Action Date": e.E_Approve_Time,
            Remarks: e.Entity_Comment,
          });
        });
       }) 
        csvStream.end();
```

Comment: Thank you Jitendra for your response, But Im getting error cursor.forEach is not a function. Please help.

Comment: please send data of cursor

Comment: It returns query,    Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],....,model: Model { entities_copies },
  schema: 
   Schema {
     obj: 
      { 
        Entity_Creator: [Object],
        Entity_Comment: [Object],
       .....} etc..

Comment: yes it's Query, please send a responce of Query or Schema of collection.

Comment: Schema is : const entityRegistrationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(  
    {
  Entity_For : { type : String}, 
  Entity_Class            : { type : String}, 
  Entity_Creator       : { type :   String},  
                Entity_Comment  : { type :   String},   
                Entity_EmailID   : { type :   String, index: true},    
                E_Approve_Time    : { type :   String},    
       } ,{
        timestamps: true
    })

Comment: I have updated the code. verify it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244633/discussion-between-jitendra-chauhan-and-sai).

Comment: Still Im not able to fetch the results in frontend., query is retrieving 10000 records only but stil it keeps onloading & in backend also it is writing empty datas with comma. Please suggest.

Comment: can share the response of this code